# WP. Как удалить тег(метку) у товара?

Tags: php, wordpress

`wp_set_object_terms(44723, 'Новинка', 'product_tag', true);`

Этот код добавляет метку к посту по id
А как сделать так, чтобы удалить метку у товара? Именно эту (у товара может быть несколько меток)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `wp_remove_object_terms` https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_remove_object_terms

```
wp_remove_object_terms( 44723, 777, 'product_tag' );
```

Где 777 - term_id.